# Why does a combination of u32 and PRErouting not work within iptables?

Tags: iptables

I'm currently trying to learn about advanced setups with iptables on a xubuntu gateway. I found out that it's possible to filter on specific byte values within packets with the u32 module.
For example I can detect a TLS 1.2 Client Hello message coming through the gateway with the next command

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 \
-p tcp \! -f --dport 443 \
-m state --state ESTABLISHED -m u32 --u32 \
"0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 0 & 0xFFFFFF00=0x16030100 && \
 0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 2 & 0xFF=0x01 && \
 0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 7 & 0xFFFF=0x0303" \
-j LOG --log-prefix "TLS 1.2 Client Hello detected: "
```

However, sometimes it is better to use the PREROUTING table (e.g. for messages that should not being forwarded). But if I try

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -m u32 --u32 \
"0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 0 & 0xFFFFFF00=0x16030100 && \
0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 2 & 0xFF=0x01 && \
0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 7 & 0xFFFF=0x0303"
-j LOG --log-prefix "tls 1.2 detected"
```

I don't see any new lines coming in the log file, although client hello messages are visible in Wireshark.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or why u32 doesn't working with the PREROUTING table?

Comment: for anyone trying to use this: it's better to send all packets on a specific port to the NFQUEUE and run a program that handles messages in the nfqueue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nat table is only consulted with the first packet of a connection. Check [this response](https://serverfault.com/questions/741104/iptables-redirect-works-only-for-first-packet)

Comment: I didn't expect anymore to get an answer on on my question. Thanks for posting the link!